# apostrophes - team's size vs. team size

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Which form is correct in expressions like this:
1) **team's size**
or
2) **team size**?

And a similar one: 1) **actual period length** or 2) **actual period's length**.

Is there any rule?

Comment: Could you please use these in full-sentence examples? Depending on your meaning, I think either can be correct.

Comment: Catija, well... can I ask you to provide examples whether either of these can be correct in a answer?

Comment: Considering the fact that I don't know what you mean (contextually) by  *actual period length* I can't use them in examples until you do. I will do some examples for the first one.

Answer (score 2):

#### *Team's size* vs *Team size*

> In basketball, any **team's size** is limited to 11 players.

This is a normal possessive phrase, in other words:

> In basketball, the **size of the team** is limited to 11 players.

---

In the case of *team size*, it's a compound noun.

> The optimal **team size** for group projects is five.